Fixing problem with simple brushed DC motor not moving
I was following a tutorial for a brushed motor (this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbcJvGk72HY), and it spins. However, there is a problem when the coils of the stator is directly parallel to the magnets. There can be no change in magnetic field when it is in this position, and thus the motor can't be turned on automatically. It might also be because the brushes being used in the setup (paper clips), are touching both commutator plates. Is there any easy solution around this? Maybe orienting another set of magnets at an angle?
Attached below are a reference images for the position which the motor breaks.



Put the windings so they are not directly opposite each other, that will give a turning force to start from any position.

This is a common problem with motors of that type. You solve it by slightly offsetting (rotating) one of both of the brushes relative to the position of the rotating coil. This makes the motor self-starting but also means that when run in reverse, the motor will turn at a slightly lower speed than it does when running in forward.

Hello, thank you for your asnwer, but I don't really seem to understand. Could you send some sort of reference diagram of your proposed setup? Thanks a lot.

Move the contact point of one paper clip against the rotating copper commutator upwards by bending and shaping it a little bit and move the contact point of the other a bit downwards similarly. This means a line connecting the two contact points will not be horizontal, but tilted a bit either way off of horizontal.

Okay, got it. Thank you!
